# Prove a formula about binoms

Tags: combinatorics

I want to prove that $\binom{n}{n/2} \leq 2^{n-1}$
[Assuming $n$ is even]

I've tried to do that but I didn't succeed.

Comment: Have you considered using induction?

Answer (score 3):

It is not true for $n=0$, but is for $n \gt 0$ and even.

$\displaystyle {n \choose n/2} \frac{1}{2^{n}}$ is the probability of tossing a fair coin $n$ times and getting an equal number of heads and tails.  This is half the probability of tossing a fair coin $n-1$ times and getting exactly one more or fewer heads than tails, and so must be less than or equal to $\frac12$.

$$\displaystyle {n \choose n/2} \frac{1}{2^{n}} \le \frac12 \implies {n \choose n/2} \le {2^{n-1}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$(1+1)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}$$
$$(1-1)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}$$

Now, depending on the parity of $0.5n$ add or subtract the above relations....

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer If you add the two relations, you get $$\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} \binom{2n}{2k+1} =2^{n-1}$$If you subtract them you get $$\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} \binom{2n}{2k} =2^{n-1}$$ Now, since all terms are positive, one term is less than the sum....